# Is the error function only = 1 at infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, error-function

I have a little question regarding the error function that disturbs me a lot:

Let us consider the classical error function defined as:

erf($z$) $= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{z} e^{-t^2} dt$

It is well-known [1] that for $z= \infty,$ erf($z$) = 1. My question may be idiotic but is the following one: is the error function only equals to 1 at $z= \infty$ ? In other words, is the error function never reaches the value of 1 before the strict value $z= \infty$ ? Don't tell me to refer to tables of values of erf($z$) because the latter are based on numerical integrations and thus subjected to numerical uncertainties.

Thank you very much for your help,

Regards

[1] http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html

Comment: Yes for the question in title, as the error function is strictly increasing since the integrand is strictly positive.

Comment: The value of the integral starts at zero and grows toward the asymptote one. It reaches one only when z reaches infinity (so to speak, b/c/ infinity is not a number).

Comment: It does take on the value $1$ in the complex plane, however: the roots with smallest absolute value are at roughly $-1.35 \pm 1.99i$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter I wanted to write an answer, but it is basically your comment. Maybe you should answer?

Comment: @SK19 By writing $z$, I think OP wants the domain to be complex. As there's already a answer for the complex case, I think there's no need to add one for the real case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see that:
$$\frac{d}{dz} \text{erf}(z) = \frac{2e^{-z^2}}{\sqrt{\pi}}>0$$
Therefore the function is strictly increasing.

- As $\text{erf}(0)=0$  then $\text{erf}(x)>0$.
- $\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t^2} dt=1$

Take $x>0$.

$$\frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t^2} dt = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t^2} dt + \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{x}^{\infty} 
e^{-t^2} dt $$
$$1 = \text{erf}(x) + \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-t^2} dt$$
$$1- \text{erf}(x) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{-t^2} dt >0$$

$$1>\text{erf}(x)$$

Answer (score 2):

*Probably not very useful.*

In the [linked page](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Erf.html), they give the asymptotic series
$$\text{erf}(x)=1-\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{\pi }}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n} x^{-(2n+1)}$$ and a very accurate asymptotics would be
$$\text{erf}(x)=1-e^{-x^2} \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }
   x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)\right)$$

For $x=10$, the "exact" value is 
$$0.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999791151$$ while the above truncated expression gives
$$0.99999999999999999999999999999999999999999999790117$$

**Edit**

After GNU Supporter's comment, consider
$$a_n=(-1)^n \frac{(2n-1)!!}{2^n} x^{-(2n+1)}$$ This gives
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{2 n+1}{2 x^2}\approx \frac n {x^2}$$ which decreases very fast.

Comment: I find it useful as it gives a second-order estimation.  To answer OP's question, it remains to set $x$ large enough so that $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi }
   x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right) > 0.$$